# Decorate each item resolved in a collection with Castle Windsor

Tags: collections, castle-windsor, decorator

Suppose I have an interface with multiple base implementations:

```
interface IPrinter
{
    void Print();
}

class Printer1 : IPrinter
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType());
    }
}

class Printer2 : IPrinter
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType());
    }
}
```

I also have a decorator implementation:

```
class ModifyingPrinter : IPrinter
{
    private readonly IPrinter _printer;

    public ModifyingPrinter(IPrinter printer)
    {
        _printer = printer;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.Write("Modified ");
        _printer.Print();
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a service which requires a collection of the interface:

```
class Service
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPrinter> _printers;
    public Service(IEnumerable<IPrinter> printers)
    {
        _printer = printer;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (var printer in _printer)
        {
            printer.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like is for `Service` to have `Printer1` and `Printer2` in the collection, each decorated with `ModifyingPrinter` so that the output of `Service.Print()` is:

```
Modified Printer1
Modified Printer2
```

I've tried registering the classes as follows:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(
    new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel, true));

container.Register(Component.For<IPrinter>()
                            .ImplementedBy<ModifyingPrinter>()
                            .LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<IPrinter>()
                            .ImplementedBy<Printer1>());
container.Register(Component.For<IPrinter>()
                            .ImplementedBy<Printer2>());

container.Register(Component.For<Service>());
```

But this results in the following output:

```
Modified Printer1
Printer1
Printer2
```

It appears that Windsor's `CollectionResolver` is supplying one each of all implementations of `IPrinter` (which is understandable) instead of recognizing that `ModifyingPrinter` is a decorator and using it to wrap the other two implementations.

**My question:**  Is there a way to register these classes so that the collection contains only decorated base implementations?

I read in another post somewhere that I can create an interceptor and register `Printer1` and `Printer2` with the interceptor, but I'd like to keep to the decorator pattern if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Castle.Windsor cannot do what I'm looking for out of the box.  I tried looking into creating a new resolver to handle this scenario, but didn't get very far.

In the end, I restructured to use a true factory to decorate the classes.

```
class PrinterModifierFactory : IPrinterModifierFactory
{
    private Func<IPrinter, IPrinter> _decorate;
    private IEnumerable<IPrinter> _printers;

    public PrinterModifierFactory(Func<IPrinter, IPrinter> decorate,
                                  IEnumerable<IPrinter> printers)
    {
        _decorate = decorate;
        _printers = printers;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IPrinter> GetAll()
    {
        return _printers.Select(_decorate);
    }
}
```

Then I modified my service to simply receive and instance of this factory (via the interface, of course) instead of the `IEnumerable<IPrinter>`.

```
class Service
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPrinter> _printers;
    private IPrinterModifierFactory factory;

    public Service(IPrinterModifierFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        _Initialize();

        foreach (var printer in _printers)
        {
            printer.Print();
        }
    }

    void _Initialize()
    {
        if (_printers != null) return;

        _printers = factory.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

(I've omitted details like `null` checks for brevity.)

Finally, in the installer, I could register the factory and the decorating method.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IPrinterModifierFactory>()
                            .ImplementedBy<PrinterModifierFactory>());
Func<IPrinter, IPrinter> decorator = p => new ModifyingPrinter(p);
container.Register(Component.For<Func<IPrinter, IPrinter>>()
                            .Instance(decorator));
```

The answer was to be a bit more explicit in my architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to achieve the expected result:

- use a [decorator](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Decorators.ashx?HL=decorator) and wrap the `Print` method in the decorated behavior. This feels like a logical behavior since you may not want to create a `IPrinter` that doesn't have the intended behavior but rather a decorating behavior.
- use a [factory method](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx?HL=method,factory#Using_a_delegate_as_component_factory_6) to resolve your IPrinters with the method newing a decorating printer around the expected printer. I fear this may be a bit complicated to follow since if you want to benefit from the convention based configuration you will have to filter out the decorator. But it should work for your needs